# How do i get SublimeCodeIntel Jump to Symbol working for php

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, editor, sublimetext

I'm desperate to migrate to sublime text from netbeans but I cannot get the SublimeCodeIntel plugin working correctly. I've read all the documentation and the relevant threads on the sublimetext forums and I'm certain i've got the necessary dependencies installed (including libpcre++-dev) and I've run build.sh successfully. I can get autocomplete working using CTRL+Space however the feature I really need to work is the jump to symbol. I've created a project for my php code and I've tried the various key bindings and mouse clicks but I cannot get the jump feature to work. I don't get any feedback whatsoever when I do an alt+click or any of the other hotkeys the documentation suggests. I'm running ubuntu 11.11.

My console output is as follows:

```
startup, version: 2139 linux x64 channel: stable
executable: /home/brandon/Apps/SublimeText2/sublime_text
working dir: /home/brandon
packages path: /home/brandon/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages
settings path: /home/brandon/.config/sublime-text-2/Settings
PackageSetup not required
error parsing session: No data at: 0:0
Py_GetProgramName(): sublime_text
Py_GetExecPrefix(): .
Py_GetProgramFullPath(): /home/brandon/bin/sublime_text
Py_GetPath(): ./lib/python26.zip:./lib/python2.6/:./lib/python2.6/plat-linux2:./lib/python2.6/lib-tk:./lib/python2.6/lib-old:./lib/python2.6/lib-dynload
Py_GetPythonHome(): .
catalogue loaded
found 4 files for base name Default.sublime-keymap
found 2 files for base name Default.sublime-mousemap
found 3 files for base name Main.sublime-menu
Reloading plugin /home/brandon/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Default/comment.py
Reloading plugin /home/brandon/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Default/copy_path.py
Reloading plugin /home/brandon/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Default/delete_word.py
Reloading plugin /home/brandon/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Default/detect_indentation.py
Reloading plugin /home/brandon/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Default/duplicate_line.py
Reloading plugin /home/brandon/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Default/echo.py
Reloading plugin /home/brandon/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Default/exec.py
Reloading plugin /home/brandon/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Default/fold.py
Reloading plugin /home/brandon/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Default/font.py
Reloading plugin /home/brandon/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Default/goto_line.py
Reloading plugin /home/brandon/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Default/indentation.py
Reloading plugin /home/brandon/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Default/kill_ring.py
Reloading plugin /home/brandon/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Default/mark.py
Reloading plugin /home/brandon/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Default/new_templates.py
Reloading plugin /home/brandon/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Default/open_file_settings.py
Reloading plugin /home/brandon/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Default/paragraph.py
Reloading plugin /home/brandon/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Default/save_on_focus_lost.py
Reloading plugin /home/brandon/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Default/scroll.py
Reloading plugin /home/brandon/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Default/side_bar.py
Reloading plugin /home/brandon/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Default/sort.py
Reloading plugin /home/brandon/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Default/swap_line.py
Reloading plugin /home/brandon/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Default/switch_file.py
Reloading plugin /home/brandon/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Default/transform.py
Reloading plugin /home/brandon/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Default/transpose.py
Reloading plugin /home/brandon/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Default/trim_trailing_white_space.py
Reloading plugin /home/brandon/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Diff/diff.py
Reloading plugin /home/brandon/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Git/git.py
Reloading plugin /home/brandon/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/HTML/encode_html_entities.py
Reloading plugin /home/brandon/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/HTML/html_completions.py
Reloading plugin /home/brandon/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Package Control/Package Control.py
Reloading plugin /home/brandon/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/SublimeCodeIntel/python_codeintel.py
loading bindings
loading pointer bindings
Package Control: Skipping automatic upgrade, last run at 2011-11-28 09:59:44, next run at 2011-11-28 21:59:44 or after
found 1 files for base name Default.sublime-theme
theme loaded
app ready
pre session restore time: 0.186002
startup time: 0.261272
loaded 937 snippets
```

My .codeintel/config is:

```
{
        "PHP": {
                "php": '/usr/bin/php',
                "phpExtraPaths": [],
                "phpConfigFile": 'php.ini'
        }
}
```

I had a friend of mine who has sublime text installed try it on his Macbook and he was able to get it working. Any insights into what i might be missing?

Answer (score 2):

Have you confirmed that `libpcre++-dev` is installed? I'm also using Ubuntu (11.04 and 11.11) and found that it was not installed by default.

Assuming you don't have it installed, you'll want to grab that and `python-dev` and then re-run the `build.sh` script in `Packages/SublimeCodeIntel/src`. The [readme](https://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeCodeIntel) explains this in a bit more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is, Ubuntu has by default Alt+Click set to dragging window functionality. You can check this by seeing a little hand arrow when altclicking. To disable this I used https://askubuntu.com/questions/80623/how-to-disable-altclick-from-moving-windows

Answer (score 0):

Goto Preferences, open Preferences.sublime-settings and paste the below line..

{
    "inhibit_completions": false,
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Vintage"
    ]
}